# Python normalize datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am working in a system where 24th hour exists. I have a large array of datetime.

Hence, if I can have time as:

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 25, 0, 0)
```

it represents `'2012-01-24 24:00'.`

I want to normalize t1 and obtain:

```
normalized_t1 = '2012-01-24'
```

Currently if I normalize t1 as:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex([t1, t1]).normalize()
```

I get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-25', '2012-01-25'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a pythonic way instead of using if statements, etc.

Comment: So your day starts from 01:00 and ends at 24:59?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subtract an hour to make the date correspond to what you require.

```
>>> t1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 25, 0, 0)
>>> t1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2012-01-25'
>>> t1 -= datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> t1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2012-01-24'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method of date time object will be,

```
import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
t1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 25, 0, 0)
print t1.strftime(fmt)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is what I found](https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/)

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 25, 0, 0)
print "{}-{}-{}".format(t1.year, t1.month, t1.day)
```

outputs

```
2012-1-25
```